# Binary Classification Neural Network: both Nan loss and NaN predictions

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

This model tries to predict two states based on an array with 400 numbers. During the first training round the model starts with loss on the first +- 200 samples, and then goes into Nan loss. The accuracy stays around 50% and when I print the predictions for the test set, it only predicts NaN. My `X_train` has a shape of `(1934, 400, 1)` and my `y_train` a shape of `(1934,)`. I already tried checking for NaNs in the dataset, but there were none.

My model looks like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(400,1), activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0,2))
model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0,2))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0,2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01)

# mean_squared_error = mse
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=opt,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=3, validation_split = 0.1, shuffle=True, batch_size = 64)
```

edit: Solved by changing the activation function to tanh. Sigmoid stays sigmoid!

Comment: Should the `Dropout`s be `0.2`?

Comment: It is a bit hard to debug this without the data and the model output during training. Your model may be suffering from exploding gradients. Try setting `clipnorm=1.0` (or other suitable values) for the optimizer.

Comment: In addition to what nemo said, maybe try adding a bit of weight decay

Comment: LSTMs, according to Keras documentation, should use 'tanh', which is its default activation. Since it's recurrent (with 400 steps!!!), it's probably the cause of exploding outputs. Imagine a single weight matrix that happens to increase the values of the inputs, even if just a little. Now elevate this increase to the power 400.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved with changing the activation functions to "tanh". Seems that dropout should be 0.2 instead of 0,2 also, but this wasn't the cause of the problem.